# get result after intent got from file browser

Tags: android, android-intent

My app can save and load a custom type of files, let's say .foo.

My manifest tells this :

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.LoadActivity"
    android:label="dummy">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="file" />
        <data android:host="*" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.foo" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

With this, I can launch my activity when a browser try to open a .foo file.

But in my activity, `onCreate()` is called, but not `onActivityResult()`, how can I get the path to the file that get clicked ?

I've been searching the doc for a long time, cannot figure this out.

Comment: "But in my activity, onCreate() is called, but not onActivityResult(), why ?" -- because `onActivityResult()` is not supposed to be called, presumably. That is only called if *you* called `startActivityForResult()`. There is nothing in your question that indicates that you made such a call. Please explain why you think `onActivityResult()` *should* be called.

Comment: How can I get the file that led to my activity then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I get the path to the file that get clicked?

You can simply retrieve it from the incoming `Intent`. Just call:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.getData().toString();
```

To answer your whole question:

> But in my activity, onCreate() is called, but not onActivityResult(), why ?

You can find the answer directly from the [method Javadoc](http://goo.gl/P4BLwN):

> *Called when an activity **you** launched exits [...]*

This is not your case. `onActivityResult` is called only on activities that you launched (from your code). In the scenario that you're describing your activity is called from another application (the browser).

`onActivityResult` will be called after the ending of an activity you launched with method `startActivityForResult`

Comment: Ok I get it, but since the call come from the browser (ES explorer, for instance), how can I get the file ?

Comment: You should be able to get it from the `onCreate` callback.
Just simply call:  
  
`Intent intent = getIntent();`  
`intent.getData().toString();`

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the file that led to my activity then ?

Call `getIntent()` in `onCreate()` to get the `Intent` that was used to start your activity. On there, `getData()` will return the `Uri` pointing to the file.